# Storing array into Csv : <<': undefined methodmap' for "Coco":String

Tags: ruby

I am trying to scrape the allocine webpage as an exercice and I can get the movie titles but i can't store them into a csv file.

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'csv'

url = "http://www.allocine.fr/film/meilleurs/"

html_file = open(url).read
html_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html_file)
array = []

html_doc.search('.no_underline').each do |element|
    array << element.text.strip
end

puts array

csv_options = { col_sep: ',', force_quotes: true, quote_char: '"' }
filepath    = 'allocine.csv'

CSV.open(filepath, 'wb', csv_options) do |csv|
  array.each  { |item| csv << item }
end
```

Here is my error message : Coco
Forrest Gump
La Ligne verte
Your Name
La Liste de Schindler
12 hommes en colère
Lion
Le Parrain
Django Unchained
Tu ne tueras point
The Dark Knight, Le Chevalier Noir
Gran Torino
Le Seigneur des anneaux : le retour du roi
Pulp Fiction
Les Evadés
Le Seigneur des anneaux : la communauté de l'anneau
Fight Club
Le Roi Lion
The Greatest Showman
Le Seigneur des anneaux : les deux tours
Vol au-dessus d'un nid de coucou
Les Enfants Loups, Ame & Yuki
Au Revoir Là-haut
Interstellar
Gladiator

/Users/laburthe/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/2.4.0/csv.rb:1705:in `<<': undefined method`map' for "Coco":String (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  tap
    from scrap.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    from scrap.rb:22:in`each'
    from scrap.rb:22:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/laburthe/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/2.4.0/csv.rb:1299:in`open'
    from scrap.rb:21:in `'

Comment: `csv << ` accepts/expects an array. You pass it a single string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `csv` object doesn't accept a string because it does expect an array that represents a whole row/line.

So, maybe this is what you want

```
CSV.open(filepath, 'wb', csv_options) do |csv|
  array.each  { |item| csv << [item] }
end
```